# Criteria problem with $in operator in some cases (Kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

The following query does not return any results:

```
val names = mutableListOf("toto")
Criteria().orOperator(
    mutableListOf(
        Criteria("fieldA.name").`in`(names),
        Criteria("fieldB.name").`in`(names)
    )
)
```

But I know that some results should have returned. Moreover the following query returns some results:

```
Criteria().orOperator(
    mutableListOf(
        Criteria("fieldA.name").`is`(names[0]),
        Criteria("fieldB.name").`is`(names[0])
    )
)
```

In the log, I can see:
Executing count: { "$or" : [{ "fieldA.urn" : { "$in" : **[[**"toto"**]]**}}, { "fieldB.urn" : { "$in" : **[[**"toto"**]]**}}]} in collection: fields

The double brackets do not seem "normal" to me. I believe it is a bug. Could you confirm it?
same for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.7.9, org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:3.4.8 and org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:4.10.2

I tried to use this criteria:

```
Criteria
    .where("fieldA.name").`in`(names)
    .orOperator(Criteria.where("fieldB.name").`in`(names))
```

But as expected, the logging shows the same mongodb query.

Thanks,
Val

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Criteria` class provides to two overloaded functions for `$in` operator. These are:

`in(Object... values)` and `in(Collection<?> values)`

One takes a varargs parameter and the other takes a collection of values. From the query logs, it's clear that your call is resolving to `varargs` version of the function, and that is considering your passed parameter as one element which is a list. To fix this, you can try spreading your list to varargs like this:

```
val names = mutableListOf("toto")
Criteria().orOperator(
    mutableListOf(
        Criteria("fieldA.name").`in`(*names.toTypedArray()),
        Criteria("fieldB.name").`in`(*names.toTypedArray())
    )
)
```